# incorrect syntax near the key word 'UPDATE'

Tags: c#

tengo un problema cuando intento actualizar los datos de mi tabla me lanza este error:

> incorrect syntax near the key word 'UPDATE'.[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTMwA.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y quieres que adivinemos cual es el problema sin ver tu clausula update? Pues me deje la bola de cristal en los otros pantalones...

Comment: Eso significa que tienes un error de sintaxis cerca de la palabra clave UPDATE, pero no te podemos ayudar sí no agregas el código, el query...

Comment: Ahora veo que pusiste una imagen. Copia mejor el código aqui en lugar de poner una captura de pantalla

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, necesitaríamos el código de tu metodo `actualizar`. Sospecho que ahi haces algo que modifica el update, provocando el error.

Comment: Tienes que copiar el código y no tomarle foto

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar parametro en el codigo y NUNCA concatener en el string

La estructura deberia ser como la siguiente:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))   
{   
    conn.Open();   

    string query = "UPDATE NombreTabla  SET campo1=@param1, campo2 = @param2 WHERE id = @paramid";   
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);   

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", TextBox1.Text);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Convert.ToInt32(Textbox2.Text));  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramid", Convert.ToInt32(Textbox3.Text));  

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   

}
```

si el metodo que usas cnn.actualizar() no te deja asignar parametros entonces deberias cambiarlo, quizas definirle una `List<SqlParameter>` para poder especificar desde fuera los parametros que asignes al update